# Adaptive log4j appender which ignores log directives under load

Tags: java, log4j

I have a specific log category which - in the event of "high load", I'd like to choose not to log.

The log data is written to the file system, so in this scenario, I'd define 'high load' as the file growing at a rate above a specific threshold over time.

Is there an existing appender which is able to recognize that the file is growing abnormally fast, and then ignore log directives?

If not, is this something that is within the scope of a custom appender?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no existing log4j appender that can do such a thing.

However, a custom appender could be developed (e.g. as a subclass of an existing appender). It would have to keep track of its throughput, and discard messages accordingly.

The custom appender approach has two caveats:

1. In a larger system, the appender would run in the Log4J log server, not in your application. The application would send messages to the log server, which subsequently calls the appender to store it (in a file, database, whatever). Now, the main effort here is to get the message to the log server, so discarding the message on the log server would be a huge waste of resources. Instead, you would have to discard it on the client-side (that is in your application).
2. Constructing the message is sometimes expensive (creating objects, strings, parameterized messages, gather statistics, measure time etc.). Again, it's a waste of resources to do this if the appender were to discard the results.

Still, it can be done.

Firstly, your throughput aware appender would have to be a subclass of SocketAppender, so that the network overhead is not expended for nothing.
Secondly, the appender would have to offer a highly efficient way for the application to find out if messages are currently being discarded. Then, in your application, you can write efficient code like:

```
if (MyLogHelper.isActuallyLogging(LOGGER, Level.DEBUG)) {
    LOGGER.debug(constructExpensiveMessage());
}
```